# Using session.query(cls).from_statement to do insert with "on conflict ... returning *" multiple times does not reflect changes until commit

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm using sqlalchemy 1.3.0 with postgres 11. I'm trying to use an `INSERT` with `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE ... RETURNING *` in order to create an instance of my model.

```py
class Model(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'mytable'
    pk = Column(String(64), primary_key=True)
    col2 = Column(String(64))

    @classmethod
    def upsert(cls, pk, col2, session):
        return session.query(cls).from_statement(
            text(
                """
                INSERT INTO {} (pk, col2) VALUES (:pk, :col2)
                ON CONFLICT (pk) DO UPDATE SET col2=EXCLUDED.col2 RETURNING *;
                """.format(cls.__tablename__)
            )
        ).params(pk=pk, col2=col2).one()

obj1 = Model.upsert(1, 'one', session)
obj2 = Model.upsert(1, 'two', session)
print(obj2.col2) ----> outputs "one"
session.commit()
print(obj2.col2) ----> outputs "two"
```

The second upsert does issue the correct command to the database, but printing the col2 attribute of the object returned shows the value of the column that was inserted during the *first* upsert. Then, if I do a `session.commit()`, the object magically gets updated to show the new value. What am I missing? I want the object returned from the function to reflect the values that the row was updated to, without having to do a commit, because I want this along with several other things to happen within a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the `session.commit()` was essentially expiring the object so that the following `print(obj2.col2)` would requery the database to populate its attributes.

In order to have obj2.col2 be the correct value without committing (and requerying the database), I just needed to do `session.expunge(obj1)` before the second upsert call to create obj2.